# Difference Between Details view, Data list, List view and Form view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know more detailed about difference between

> - Data List,
> - Details View,
> - Form View and
> - List View.

And when we should use them in creating websites?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, then come back with a specific problem. This kind of question is too broad [meanwhile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/395968/284240).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Details View**

> DetailView shows the details for the row in a separate space.

**Tutorials**

[DetailsView Example in ASP.NET using C#](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/detailsview.html)

[How to use DetailsView in asp.net](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/11/aspnet-detailsview-example-how-to-use.html)

[DetailsView Control Example](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/detailsview.aspx)

**DataList**

> The DataList control is, like the Repeater control, used to display a
>   repeated list of items that are bound to the control. However, the
>   DataList control adds a table around the data items by default. The
>   DataList control may be bound to a database table, an XML file, or
>   another list of items.

**Tutorials**

[Working with the DataList Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23559/Working-with-the-DataList-Control)

[Displaying Data with the DataList and Repeater Controls (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-cs)

**ListView**

> The ASP.NET ListView control enables you to bind to data items that
>   are returned from a data source and display them. You can display data
>   in pages. You can display items individually, or you can group them.

**Tutorial**

[Complete ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5)

**Form View**

> Formview is intended for insert/update/view of a single record.

**Tutorial**

[How to use FormView ItemTemplate and Eval() in asp.net](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-formview-example-how-to-use.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links!

Answer (score -1):

Happy reading :)

- [Details View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Data List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [List View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)
- [Form View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This isn't an answer, just google results...

Comment: @Aristos I agree, but the question is rather broad. I'd be happy to upvote a better answer if there was one.

Comment: some answer small and nice to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/397833/159270  In any case your answer did not help at all, nether show that you know what are the real / practical diferents.

Comment: @Aristos lol I was too lazy to search myself... hahaha I will vote to close this question as an exact duplicate. Thanks :)

Comment: @Amarnath Thank u and as i am beginner in asp.net pls can i know some links for complete ASP.NET tutorials with examples. It would be helpful to improve my knowledge. Thanks